# get list of child class in python

Tags: python

I have some class like this

```
class Base(object):
 __child_class__ = []

class ChildA(Base): pass

class ChildB(Base): pass
```

What I need to do for the interpreter to automatically fill the argument `__child_class__` by all the child class so I can have this result

```
Base.__child_class__ = [ChildA, ChildB]
```

Do I need the `metaclass` for this?

Comment: You probably do need a metaclass. Other solution would be to scan all files/classes and search for `Base`.

Comment: @freakish: You don't. See the dupe. My answer there does also give a metaclass and a class decorator solution.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh, that's nice. Didn't know that.